# SamlSecurityToken serialization

Tags: serialization

I know SecurityToken serialization should be a simple thing. Have done it in the past with tokens from Active STS. However, now when I am trying to do it using a token from Passive STS flow, getting an error from the WriteToken method that

"the private key is not present in the X.509Certificate".

The pretty straight forward code I am using is:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var writer = XmlWriter.Create(new StringWriter(sb), new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true });

        SecurityTokenHandlerCollection handlers = SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.CreateDefaultSecurityTokenHandlerCollection();
        SecurityTokenHandler handler = handlers[securityToken];

        handler.WriteToken(writer, securityToken);
```

This code needs to be in a client of STS where the certificate private key would obviously be not there.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah! Got the answer!

I was mixing .Net 3.5 Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll based code in .Net 4.5. Once I moved the above code to serialize the token into .Net 4.5, it worked as expected.

(Was banging my head on this for last 2 days :()